# Unity C# Detect all game objects above

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, collider

I want my player to detect all gameobjects in layer 8. I have found a code that detect all game objects above but it just detect on x=0 line like in these graphs,

[What It does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utrpu.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1demY.png)

```
   RaycastHit[] hitsUp = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, transform.up, distance);
   RaycastHit[] hitsDown = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, -transform.up, distance);
   foreach (RaycastHit hit in hitsUp)
   {
       if (hit.collider.gameObject.layer == 8)
       {
            Physics.IgnoreCollision(hit.collider, GetComponent<Collider>());
       }
   }
   foreach (RaycastHit hit in hitsDown)
   {
       if (hit.collider.gameObject.layer == 8)
       {
            Physics.IgnoreCollision(hit.collider, GetComponent<Collider>(), false);
       }
   }
```

How can i solve this issue? Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Raycast is only catching "hits" that are directly above the player, as it follows a straight line.

You could place all the gameObjects within a single parent object, and loop through each gameObject, checking its layer, then whether or not it's above or below you

Something like this could work:

```
public Transform parent;
private Collider myCollider;

private void Start() 
{
    myCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
}

private void DetectObjects()
{
    //Loop through each object above/below
    foreach (Transform child in parent)
    {
        GameObject childObj = child.gameObject;
        if (childObj.layer == 8) //Is the object on the correct layer?
        {
            if (child.position.y > transform.position.y) Physics.IgnoreCollision(childObj.GetComponent<Collider>(), myCollider);             //GameObjects above the player
            else if (child.position.y < transform.position.y) Physics.IgnoreCollision(childObj.GetComponent<Collider>(), myCollider, false); //GameObjects below the player
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should try to store the Collider component instead of using `GetComponent<>()` as it's very slow.

Depending on whether or not the objects are being created/deleted you could store the colliders for them as well, which would improve the performance of the code by quite a bit, for example:

```
public Transform parent;
private Collider myCollider;
private Collider[] objColliders;

private void Start() 
{
    myCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
    //If any gameObject is inactive it can also be grabbed by adding true as a paramater
    objColliders = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>();
}

private void DetectObjects()
{
    GameObject childObj;
    //Loop through colliders
    for (int i = 0; i < objColliders.Length; i++)
    {
        childObj = objColliders[i].gameObject; //Store as gameObject reference
        if (childObj.layer == 8)
        {
            if (childObj.transform.position.y > transform.position.y) Physics.IgnoreCollision(objColliders[i], myCollider);             //GameObjects above the player
            else if (childObj.transform.position.y < transform.position.y) Physics.IgnoreCollision(objColliders[i], myCollider, false); //GameObjects below the player
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add layermask filter into your Raycast.

```
int layerMask = 1 << 8; // - detects raycasts only on 8 layer
RaycastHit[] hitsUp = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up, distance, layerMask);
RaycastHit[] hitsDown = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, -transform.up, distance, layerMask);
```

`foreach` aren't needed.